# mobile vs desktop interface

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a web application which will be a hybrid between a desktop and a mobile version.

The interface is constructed with Bootstrap 3.0 and with `max-width:767px` the interface switches to the mobile version

In desktop-mode the dark sidebar to the left is always visible, and in mobile-mode the sidebar is invisible and the user can toggle between sidebar on/off

This works as expected

In the jsfiddle there are two vertical black bars which are placeholders for content.. One in the sidebar and one in the main window

- How to implement a scroll bar in the `#menu` when the content is overflowing? The scroll-able area must have 100% height of the viewport depending on the screen resolution and when using the mousewheel it must not propagate to the body

## jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gjvzn3rb/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want the menu to scroll?

You can get 100% height and scroll by changing your `#menu` css:

```
#menu {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If you want the *whole* sidebar to scroll you can use (instead of the above):

```
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:200px;
    background:#1c2b36;
    color:#c4d0d9;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The `overflow-y: scroll;` allows for scrolling only up and down.

Note that scrolling will not propagate to the body *until* you hit the top or bottom.

Comment: Giving the menu a scrolling overflow will overlap the logo. It would be better to include the logo which in that case you would give the sidebar the overflow instead. Unless he wants only the menu then there's a little bit more re-jigging to do. (instead of padding-top, it would be margin-top instead) **EDIT:** you don't need to add in another container. Just give the #sidebar an overflow and you're set.

Comment: only `#menu` needs to scroll.. :) `#logo` must stay in the top

Comment: Then the first bit off css should help.  :)

Comment: This works.. But why has the background in `#main` only the height of the viewport? When you scroll down the background ends at the fold

Comment: Because you set `#main` to be `height: 100%`.  Remove this and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the menu to scroll, change your `#menu` to the following:

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gjvzn3rb/15/

**Note: the logo will remain at the top while the menu scrolls**

---

Alternatively, if you want the whole sidebar to scroll:

```
#sidebar { 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Add an `overflow-y:scroll;` to your sidebar so that when it does overflow, you can scroll in it without the body content scrolling as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/gjvzn3rb/13/

Answer (score 0):

How to make an HTML-element scrollable when the content overflows:

Make a scrollbar when the content overflows in **height** / vertically:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Make a scrollbar when the content overflows in **width** / horizontally:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Make a scrollbar when the content overflows in BOTH **width and height**:

```
overflow: scroll;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you take out the z-index:-1; and add overflow:scroll; that should achieve what your are trying to do.
Like this:

```
#menu 
{
  position:absolute;    
  width:100%;
  padding-left:200px;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  background:#f0f3f4;
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: its not the main but the sidebar

Comment: Oops, my apologies. The same technique will work by changing the CSS selector to the proper div as seen in the accepted answer. I have edited my answer.